# SQL: Not a simple left/right join problem

Tags: sql

I have two tables both with 2 columns (Name[string], value[integer]) 
I am trying to join the two to display the differences between the sum(value) of each Name.  e.g.

Table1(t1):

```
N1  2
N1  3
N2  4
N3  5
```

Table(t2):

```
N1  1
N2  1
N2  1
```

Result should look like:

```
N1 4  (5-1)
N2 2  (4-2)
N3 5  (5-0)
```

We want to assume 0 if N is missing from either one of the tables

I only know how to do the join if the names exist in both table but i do not know how to handle replacing empty results with value of 0 if name is missing in either table.

My current query:

```
select t1.name, t2.name, t1.Sum-t2.Sum as "Diff"
from (select t1.name, sum(t1.value) as Sum from t1 group by t1.name) t1 
inner join
(select t2.name, sum(t2.value) as Sum from t2 group by t2.name) t2 
on t1.name = t2.name
```

The result ignores N3 because N3 is missing from t1.

thank you

Comment: Replace the INNER JOIN with a LEFT or FULL JOIN first.      Then, look up the SQL function COALESCE, which will help you deal with NULL values.

Comment: Also, indicate what SQL product you are using (Microsoft-SQL, Oracle, mySQl ,etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate both tables using CTEs (Common Table Expressions) and then join them using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, as in:

```
with
l as (
  select name, sum(value) as total
  from table1
  group by name
),
r as (
  select name, sum(value) as total
  from table2
  group by name
)
select
  coalesce(l.name, r.name) as name,
  coalesce(l.total, 0) - coalesce(r.total, 0) as difference
from l
full outer join r on l.name = r.name
order by coalesce(l.name, r.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN and ISNULL

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.name, y.name) as Name,
       ISNULL(x.sumValues, 0) - ISNULL(y.sumValues, 0) as ValueDiff
FROM
(SELECT name, SUM(value) AS sumValues FROM t1 GROUP BY name) x
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT name, SUM(value) AS sumValues FROM t2 GROUP BY name) y
        ON x.name = y.name;
```

Comment: The `ISNULL()` function is not a generic function broadly available in most common databases compared to `COALESCE()`. However, your query should work and is very similar to the one the OP presents. +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple method is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select name, sum(value)
from ((select name, value
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select name, -value
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by name;
```

The `join` is a bit messy because it can result in duplicated and missing values, unless done very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

input:

```
create table t1 (name varchar(20),value number);
create table t2 (name varchar(20),value number);
//do inserts

select name1,nvl(sum1-sum2,sum1) from(select sum(t1.value) as sum1,t1.name name1 from t1 group by t1.name)
,(select sum(t2.value) as sum2,t2.name name2 from t2 group by t2.name) where name1=name2(+);
```

output:

```
N1  4
N2  2
N3  5
```